# Turn the three lines into a part of the body

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rebus

Using a single letter (alphabet) exactly twice turn the lines below into a part of your body.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Adding the letter

> I twice (once upright, once on its side)

turns this into

> the rebus H+, or Hand!

> [image: hand]

Comment: Creative thinking +1. I had another solution in mind.

Comment: @RogerA Keep in mind, an answer does not need to match your expected or intended solution to earn the $\color{green}\checkmark$

Comment: You can also add I upright and horizontally to make  ᵀ  ᴵ T

Comment: Per @DanielMathias comment I have accepted this answer. My intended answer was Rot 13 Zneebj jvgu n I

Comment: @RogerA ooh that's clever :)

Answer (score 12):

Ok, I think I got it now. Adding the letter

> C twice (once on its side, once reversed)

turns this into

> an L followed by a bow. This can be read as a rebus to form: Elbow!

> [image: elbow]

Comment: Doesn't that leave you with a part you need to ignore? That isn't just the one word you mention, it also includes the thing that word is designed to work with.

Answer (score 6):

Adding the letter ...

> L twice (once reversed) you get

... you get ...

> a pair of legs (inside the pants)
>
>  [image: stylized pants]

Or adding the letter ...

> J twice (one time reversed again)

... you get ...

> A hand (in a winter glove)
>
>  [image: A thick glove]

Or adding the letter ...

> V twice

... you can get a ...

> knee.
>
>  [image]

Comment: How does the last one work? What does the first V represent?

Comment: @justhalf a kneecap?

Comment: Ooh, it's one leg. I thought it's like the two legs of a stickman.

Comment: Yeah, a kneecap.  Maybe a U or O would look better, but then I couldn't do anything with the second letter.

Comment: Fascinating that the last one needed only a different caption and a slight change in size of the added letter to make what OP said the intended answer was...!

Answer (score 5):

With two of the letter

> r, lower case

I can come up with the *location* of some body parts...

> [image]
>
>  Which is N and a side-u... so... Inside you?

99% sure it's not what you're looking for, but too silly to pass up.

Answer (score 3):

**WARNING: Dad joke answer**

Use any letter except an upper-case or lower-case 's' twice, as in the examples below. All those examples have something in common: no *S*. So identify the body part *"nose"*. Depending on how you choose to pronounce things, you could achieve the same result by not using the letter 'z' instead.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Adding the letter

> C

with some turning

> to make a leg!

> [image]